# visitnum for unscheduled visits

Tags: sas

I am having the following data set: I am trying to assign the visit number for planned and unplanned visits according to the available date.If the date is different then I would like to increment the unplanned visit number (i.e:101.1,101.2). But if the date is same for unplanned visits then I would like to keep the constant visit number across the rows (i.e. 2 or more unplanned visits with same visit number i.e. 101.1,101.1).

```
    data test;
    infile cards dlm=" ";
    input subject visit event$11. date:date9.;
    format date date9.;
    cards;
    1 1  screening   10oct2017
    1 1  screening   10oct2017
    1 99 unscheduled 10oct2017
    1 99 unscheduled 11oct2017
    1 2  day-1       12oct2017
    1 2  day-1       12oct2017
    1 3  day1        16oct2017
    1 99 unscheduled 15oct2017
    ;
    run;
```

I would like to assign the avisitn as follows:

```
    1 1  screening   10oct2017   101
    1 1  screening   10oct2017   101
    1 99 unscheduled 10oct2017   101.1
    1 99 unscheduled 11oct2017   101.2
    1 2  day-1       12oct2017   102
    1 2  day-1       12oct2017   102
    1 3  day1        16oct2017   103
    1 99 unscheduled 15oct2017   103.1
```

I have tried to use the following code:

```
data test;
infile cards dlm=" ";
input subject visit event$11. date:date9.;
format date date9.;
cards;
1 1  screening   10oct2017
1 1  screening   10oct2017
1 99 unscheduled 10oct2017
1 99 unscheduled 11oct2017
1 2  day-1       12oct2017
1 2  day-1       12oct2017
1 3  day1        16oct2017
1 99 unscheduled 15oct2017
;
run;

proc sort data=test;
by subject date visit;
run;

data test1;
   set test;
   by subject date visit;

   fp = first.subject;
   lp = last.subject;
   fo = first.date;
   lo = last.date;
run;

data test2;
   set test1;
   by subject date visit;

   retain avisitn;

   prev_patient_num = lag(subject);
   prev_ordering_date = lag(date);

   if visit ne 99 then do;
       if first.subject then avisitn = 101;
       else if subject = prev_patient_num and date ne prev_ordering_date then avisitn + 1;
   end;

    if visit eq 99 then do;
        avisitn+0.1;
    end;    

   keep subject date visit avisitn;
run;
```

But, I am getting the following output

```
subject visit    date     avisitn
1        1     10OCT2017    101
1        1     10OCT2017    101
1       99     10OCT2017    101.1
1       99     11OCT2017    101.2
1       2      12OCT2017    102.2
1       2      12OCT2017    102.2
1      99      15OCT2017    102.3
1       3      16OCT2017    103.3
```

Please help me to resolve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your try you sort by subject and date.  However, in the original sample, the last two lines are disordered in date.  The last two want values (103 and 103.1) are based on unsorted data.

For sorted data you can use FLOOR before advancing by 1 when the dates change.  Tracking for too many .1 increments is a good idea.

```
data want;
  set test;
  by subject date;

  retain avisitn;

  prev_date = lag(date);

  if first.subject then do;
    avisitn = 101;
    _99s = 0;
    if visit eq 99 then do; _99s + 1; avisitn + 0.1; end;
  end;
  else
  if visit eq 99 then do;
    _99s + 1;
    if _99s = 10 then do; put 'ERROR: Too many 99s' ; abort cancel; end;
    avisitn + 0.1;
  end;
  else
  if date ne prev_date then
    avisitn = floor(avisitn) + 1;

  drop prev_date;
run;
```

If you need to process in the original order, say as in a transactional event logging order, there are solutions, however they might not be 'slick' and would require tracking states for 'weird' sequencing cases.